# Regenerate random items non-recursively

Tags: python, recursion, random, data-generation

For a database test I need to generate queries. To reduce complexity, let's say there are only "insert"- and "select"-queries, and we store only ints up to 2^64. Entries in the database are clustered on two levels: a main key and a cluster key. Each main key can have up to 2^64 unique cluster keys, which can also have up to 2^64 unique data items.

For each insert query a two chance-values are given:

1. wheter it will create a new main key and
2. wheter it will create a new cluster key for an existing item.

Also I have a pseudo random number generator, and the number of already generated items. This number is also used to seed the random generator when creating new items. See the code for how I am trying to do that:

```
from random import Random

def generate_seeds(main_chance, cluster_chance, max_generated):
        generator = Random()
        new = main_chance > generator.random()

        # increase the counter if a new item is generated
        max_generated += new

        # We chose "insert", so a new item needs to be generated
        if new:
            main_key = max_generated
            # seed the generator with that main_key
            generator.seed(main_key)
            # now determine if a whole new item will be generated
            # or an old key gets new additional items

            # Save the main seed. In case we just add an item
            # the main seed will be an old one and the main
            # seed will only be used for the new items.
            cluster_key = main_key
            add_item = cluster_chance > generator.random()
            # check if a completely new item will be generated
            if (not add_item) and new:
                return main_key, main_key, max_generated

            # We need an old main key that created a new item, so iterate
            # over the old keys until we find one that did. If no key was
            # ever used to create a completely new item, fall back to
            # seed zero, which always generates a completely new item.
            if add_item:
                # if the cluster_chance is big we might iterate very often :(
                for main_key in generator.sample(xrange(main_key), main_key):
                    generator.seed(main_key)
                    if cluster_chance < generator.random() or \
                       cluster_key == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    # special case: no items have been generated yet
                    main_key = 0
                return main_key, cluster_key, max_generated
        else:
        # The choice was "select", regenerate an old item
            choice = generator.randint(0, max_generated)
            return generate_seeds(1, cluster_chance, choice)
```

The problem: possibly very many "recursive" calls in the for-loop after add_item, which is more likely the bigger `cluster_chance` gets.

Any ideas how to solve this in a better way?

---

edit: The only idea I came up with until now is constructing a list of ints. list[n] is:

- n, if n was used to generate a completely new item with main key = cluster key
- some main key k that is < n, if a new cluster was generated for n, so main key = k, cluster key = n

The problem is, that this solution uses much memory: `d = [x for x in xrange(100000000)]` (100 Million values) use 3.183.344KiB memory, so ~32,6 Byte per value, or 32.939.450 values per gigabyte. So with 32GiB RAM one could possibly manage about 1 Billion values - good, but not good enough.

Comment: What code path executes more than one recursive call? It seems to me that after the recursive call, `main_chance` is 1, and so `new` is True, and the the non-recursive path is taken.

Comment: I'm not sure the code is doing what you want either. Don't you want `add_item = cluster_change > generator.random or main_key==0` and in the `if add_item` part, remove the for loop, and simply `return main_key, generator.randrange(main_key), max_generated`

Comment: @Anonymous there was a mistake in the code at `if cluster_chance > generator.random() or cluster_key == 0`, changed it to `if cluster_chance < generator.random() or cluster_key == 0`, added a comment above that line and now realize it's not really recursive, but recurse-ish.